# How recovery cut and paste lost data?

Tags: windows-10, data-recovery, file-recovery

### 1. Steps to reproduce

(I'm not sure, that I remember my steps 100%)

I wanted to move from folder A to folder B my photos (~20 photos). In Windows Explorer <kbd>Right_Click</kbd> to folder A → `Cut` → I move in Windows Explorer to folder B → <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>. At the same time I cut other folder to folder B. After a few minutes I see, that I'm not have my photos in folder A and folder B. I need my photos and I try recovery it.

**UPD**: Now I enable [**TeraCopy**](http://www.codesector.com/teracopy) application and get similar problem is reproduced for me. I select folder `Drake` in Windows Explorer → I press <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd> → in other folder I press <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>. I get popup:

[image: Popup]:

> Error "Не удается найти указанный файл." in Drake.
>   Would you like to make a copy and then try to delete? Press No to try again.

Now I can not find folder `Drake` in my computer.

---

### 2. Not helped

1. I pressed many times <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd>, but I don't see my photos in folder A and folder B,
2. I did not find my lost photos in recycle bin,
3. I did not find my lost photos in temp folder,
4. I did not find my photos in my computer using native Windows Search and [**Agent Rasnack**](https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack) program,
5. I did not find my photos using [**Free Clipboard Viewer**](http://www.freeclipboardviewer.com/) program,
6. I check my computer for viruses use [**HerdProtect**](http://www.herdprotect.com/) — I have not viruses.
7. <kbd>Right_Click</kbd> → `Properties` → `Previous versions` → I did not find previous versions of my folder A and folder B.
8. I did not find my photos, running full recovery search of

   - [**Recuva**](https://www.piriform.com/recuva),
   - [**GetDataBack for NTFS**](http://soft.sibnet.ru/soft/29747-getdataback-for-ntfs-v4-33--rus/),
   - [**EasyUS Data Recovery Wizard**](http://www.easeus.com/datarecoverywizard/free-data-recovery-software.htm)
   - [**Remo Recover**](http://www.remorecover.com/),
   - [**PhotoRec**](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec). PhotoRec restore 2 photos in bad quality for me.

---

### 3. Questions

1. How can I even try to recover my photos?
2. Are built-in or third-party methods without lost data use `Cut` operation?

---

### 4. Do not offer

1. Please, do not tell me, that I had copy files from folder A to folder B and then delete files from folder A. Now I understood it for all life.

---

### 5. Environment

- Windows 32-bit 10.0.14393
- TeraCopy 2.27

Thanks.

Comment: I'll add this as a comment as its not really a proper answer, just a suggestion of more recovery software to try. A relative of mine once had an external HDD corrupt with all data inaccessible (~500GB). I tried many different pieces of software to recover and got nowhere. I then tried DMDE (https://dmde.com/) and it worked a dream. I have since used it to recover files in various different scenarios with a pretty high success rate. Could be worth a try and sorry I can't offer any other more detailed help

Answer (score 0):

So Did you find your photos back? It's quite simple to use any one of the listed apps to recovery the lost photos as there are free versions for most of them. And as I know that of EaseUS software. It supports basicly 500 MB data recovery but the capacity will be increased to 2 GB when you press the SNS sharing button. And it's far enough for your needs. Hope you have already settled that done.